# Table Difference component failed with 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package that loads data from a SQL server source. After extracting records it will determine the differences between source and target using 'table difference component'.

It's a daily running package. Most of the days this will run fine but some days the package fails and gives the following error message:

> Source: DFT_STG_APR_Activity_Aud_Members Table Difference [215]
>   Description: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.get_Item(Int32
>   columnIndex)     at
>   CozyRoc.SqlServer.SSIS.TableDifference.InputInformation.AddRow(PipelineBuffer
>   buffer)     at
>   CozyRoc.SqlServer.SSIS.TableDifference.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID,
>   PipelineBuffer buffer)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr
>   bufferWirePacket)  End Error  Error: 2016-08-22 00:21:32.78     Code:
>   0xC0047022     Source: DFT_STG_APR_Activity_Aud_Members SSIS.Pipeline 
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component "Table Difference" (215) failed with
>   error code 0x8007000E while processing input "New Data Flow" (231).
>   The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput
>   method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal
>   and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.

But when I rerun the package it runs fine. Can any body help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is thrown when there is not enough memory to continue the execution of a program. Try minimizing the data loaded in memory.

Read more in this [Topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx) there are many suggestions

Comment: but when i reran the package completed successfully. Why so ?...and every day i am not getting this failure.

Comment: only ones or twise in a week it failing like this and that too after rerunning it completing sucessfully

Comment: It is depending on your memory status. When exception is thrown your memory was full. Maybe other processes are overloading memory. Try to add a code that free the memory used by Sql server before starting the operation